# How to play a background video in react-native?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to play a background video in react-native but I'm facing an issue/error which doesn't really make sense to me.

I'm new to react-native.

Here's my entire code:

```
  import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { Video } from 'expo'

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
        Change code in the editor and watch it change on your phone! Save to get a shareable url.
      </Text>
      <Card>
        <AssetExample />
      </Card>


      <Video
      source={{ uri: "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/video.gallereplay.com/artistarea/Lighthouse%20stands%20in%20Istanbul%E2%80%99s%20harbour_0554659b-5dc1-43d6-8a93-b31ec6b67f63/Cinemagraph_plain/1920x1080/cinemagraph.mp4"}}
      style={styles.backgroundVideo}
      rate={1}
      shouldPlay={true}
      isLooping={true}
      volume={1}
      muted={true}
      resizeMode="cover"
      />


    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  }, 
  backgroundVideo: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
  },
});
```

The error that I'm getting is this:

```
Error: Minified React error #130; visit [snack internals]
    at Fl ([snack internals]
    at p ([snack internals]
    at g ([snack internals]
    at [snack internals]
    at ki ([snack internals]
    at ms ([snack internals]
    at dl ([snack internals]
    at sl ([snack internals]
    at Zs ([snack internals]
    at https://snack.expo.io/web-player/39/static/js/2.208ff912.chunk.js:2:4091769
```

If you simply copy/paste my code in the snack.expo.io website, you will see the error there as well.

could someone please advice on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `import {Video} from 'expo'` to `import {Video} from 'expo-av'`